# css border radius on unknown element size

Tags: css

If I set `border-radius: 100000px` on an element it will a perfect radius. If I set `border-radius: 100%` I get a completely different result.

```css
.test {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.border1 {
  border-radius: 10000px;
}

.border2 {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
Correct
<div class="test border1"></div><br>
Weird
<div class="test border2"></div>
```

Is there a way to use another unit to get the same result as `10000px`? My element size might be unknown.

Comment: You will get border-radius:100% if height and width are same.

Comment: Even though you can use other units, it will not make any difference. You still will need to set the value to be highest than any possible dimension you really use.  100vh will fail if your element is wider  than the viewport. You could also use 1000em, or things like that, .... But I understnd that you are asking for a data related somehow to the real dimensions, and this is not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use vh length unit for same result

```
.border2 {
  border-radius: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I discovered this trick by looking at the radius on a Google Pay button. Then had to find this answer to make sure it was a legitimate trick!

Answer (score 3):

Correctly said `Cenk YAGMUR` but more than 50% of the height does not take border-radus. border-radius is more than 50% of the minimum (width, height) meaningless.

```
.border2 {
  border-radius: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Perfect radius would be a circle for you?

```
border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
```

This would give you a circle if your element is even, or a square to begin with.

Here is a fun tool that illustrates the angles on how it works
[Moz Border-radius generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-radius_generator)